# Why does client side fetch cause render looping

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch-api, app-router

I'm trying to fetch data on the client side - using 'use client' to an API route handler in NextJS. I've followed the example to use `useEffect` and `useState` to prevent looping the fetch request. Instead of rerendering with my unordered list of todos it just loops infinitely.

This is my code

```
'use client';

import React from 'react';

export default async function Page() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function getTodos() {
      const res = await fetch('/api/todo');
      const todos = await res.json();
      console.log(todos);
      setLoading(false);
      setTodos(todos);
    }
    getTodos();
  },[]);

  console.log('rendering', loading, todos);
  if (loading) return (<p>rendering</p>);
  return (
    <div className="relative todos-container shadow-xl m-2 rounded-xl w-full">
      {/* <h1 className='mb-5'>Todos</h1> */}
      <ul className='p-3'>
        {todos.map((todo, idx) => {
          return (<li className='p-3 my-3 last:mb-0 first:mt-0 bg-slate-100 rounded-lg' key={idx}>{todo.body}</li>)
        })}
      </ul>
      <div className='absolute text-center w-full -bottom-10 left-0'>
        <span className='font-extralight text-xs rounded-xl shadow m-2 p-2 bg-slate-100'>shift + enter to submit a new todo item</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My API endpoint code:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'


const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export async function GET() {
  const todos = await prisma.todo.findMany();

  return new Response(JSON.stringify(todos), {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Removing the `async` word worked.